# Two numbers $a, b$ are selected from the set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two numbers $a, b$ are selected from the set {0, 1, 2, 3,....98, 99}. What is the probability that the integer $3^a + 7^b$ ends up with the number $8$ ?

My problem is how do I find favourable cases.

Comment: There is a certain pattern in the units place, e.g. $3^1 = 3, 3^2 = 9, 3^3 = 27, 3^4 = 81, 3^5 = 243$ and you can see the patterns will go on with $3, 9, 7, 1, 3, \ldots$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to pick two integers whose last two digits are as such... (so, we don't have to deal with the situations of the boundaries). To make $3^a+7^b$ end with 8, the only possibilities are *a*=0 and *b*=1 mod 4, and *a*=3 and *b*=0 mod 4, whose probability is $(\frac1 4*\frac1 4)*2=\frac 1 8$.

Comment: +1. Short and clear. Small typo: $b=\color{red}{0}$ mod 4. Though, it does not effect the result.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you! To make 1, the exponent has to be 0.

Comment: Your second case should be $a \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $b \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$3^a\equiv \color{red}1,3,9,\color{blue}7 \pmod {10};\\
7^b\equiv \color{blue}1,\color{red}7,9,3 \pmod{10};\\
3^a+7^b\equiv \color{red}1+\color{red}7\equiv \color{blue}7+\color{blue}1\equiv 0\pmod{8}.$$

Also note that for $a,b\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,96,97,98,99\}$:
$$\color{red}{A}=\{0,4,8,...,96\} \Rightarrow n(\color{red}{A})=25;\\
\color{red}{B}=\{1,5,9,...,97\} \Rightarrow n(\color{red}{B})=25;\\
\color{blue}{A}=\{3,7,11,...,99\} \Rightarrow n(\color{blue}{A})=25;\\
\color{blue}{B}=\{0,4,8,12,...,96\} \Rightarrow n(\color{blue}{B})=25.$$
Hence:
$$\frac{{\color{red}{25}\choose 1}{\color{red}{25}\choose 1}+{\color{blue}{25}\choose 1}{\color{blue}{25}\choose 1}}{{100\choose 1}{100\choose 1}}=\frac{2\cdot 25^2}{100^2}=\frac18=0.125.$$